# Why I am getting Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind message even though I am pushing to a new repo just created

Tags: git, azure-devops, fast-forward

1. I Just created the new repository in Azure DevOps
2. I tried to pushed my project from the local computer and getting error message "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind"

I am assuming that I am getting this message because one commit is created (Added README.md, .gitignore files) automatically when I created the new repository on Azure Devops remote repository.

How can I push it to the remote repository?

I did fetch command but still getting the same message and cannot push.
Note: I am the only one working for the new repository and nobody touches or push it.

Comment: See https://www.biteinteractive.com/of-git-and-github-master-and-main/ in the "Clash of the Titans" section

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct. The existence of the commit on the other repo which does not exist at your end is the problem. You can do one of the following:

```
git push -f origin master
```

will force-push your changes.

```
git pull
```

from the remote will solve your problem, you will need to solve the merge conflicts then.

You can also solve it with `git rebase`. Finally, you can simply [remove](https://gist.github.com/CrookedNumber/8964442) the latest commit on your remote.